# Install old electron version on mac m1

Tags: npm, electron, apple-m1

I am running an old project which uses electron@v1.8 on Mac M1, but it throws an error

> Error: Failed to find Electron v1.8.8 for darwin-arm64 at https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v1.8.8/electron-v1.8.8-darwin-arm64.zip

And I don't want to use version 11+, so how can I download the specific version for such a project?

Answer (score 0):

I use nvm for the old version of node in my case 14. So I made sure that that version was uninstalled from nvm first.

Then I used `arch` to shell into my terminal using 64bit, like this `arch -x86_64 zsh` or `arch -x86_64 bash` if you are still using that.

I then used `nvm` to install the maximum version of node that I needed
`nvm install 14.18.1` and `nvm use 14.18.1`

For good measure, I deleted `node_modules` and ran `yarn install` or `npm install`

Finally, I ran `yarn dev` and it all compiled beautifully.